# How to test a file system implementation?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I am going to implement a file system in C and i'm wondering how can i test it without installing it in the kernel nor using FUSE API. Ideally what i'd like to do is to use dd command to create a virtual hard drive and interact with it using linux system calls like write and read (the idea is to not write drivers). Is that posible?

(I'm sorry if i misspelled words, but eanglish isn't my first language. Also i'm sorry if this is off-topic, it's my first question)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using a virtual machine?

Comment: I understand that it isn't your first language, but it's `english` not `eanglish`.

Comment: Why not just write a program that opens a file manually and exposes some sort of shell interface? You won't be able to access it via the operating system but seems to fit your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really implementing a file system, you can test it in virtual machine.

Otherwise, you can implement a file system in a file which exist in real file system, and implement some functions like read/write/etc...

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hard drive and virtual filesystem are a bit different things, - you write different functions and handle different requests when implementing them. Given that you implement a filesystem, your best bet on linux is to expose your filesystem via FUSE for testing. Then write different tests that will access your FUSE-based filesystem to perform various tasks.

Unfortunately testing a filesystem is hard and requires writing *many* tests. Manual testing with different software (file managers) is also required.